# determining exact bottom right corner of R plot

Tags: r, plot, par

In the **R plot below** (**run to see**), I want my **green vertical** `abline()` to exactly attach to the **bottom-right corner** of my plot; that is: exactly where the **red** and **blue** curve lines **end** in the bottom-right corner of my plot.

Keeping everything as is in my plot, What is the exact **x** of this point? `par("usr")[2]` could n't help as seen in **my code below:**

```
curve(df(x,1,28,ncp = 1.875),0,11,col="blue",lwd=3,ylim=c(0,1),xpd=T,bty="n",axes=F)
curve(df(x,1,28), add=T,col="red",lwd=2)
axis(1,pos=0)
axis(2,pos=0)

abline(v=par("usr")[2],col="green")   ## I'm using par("usr")[2] here with no success ##
```

Comment: Not as good as the answer below, but you can also get the max value of a curve when it is plotted and use this to calculate the end point - `crv <- curve(df(x,1,28), add=T,col="red",lwd=2); abline(v=max(crv$x), col="red")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default plot adds 4% extra space on each side.  So you can compute

```
size = (par("usr")[2]-par("usr")[1])/1.08
size
11
```

to get the size of the main plot  and

```
par("usr")[2]- 0.04*size   
11
```

to get the right hand edge

BTW  you can have R *not* add that space by adding  `xaxs="i"`  to your first curve statement

Comment: Strange that there is no way to actually just get that point in space given the huge number of variables in `par()`. Nice answer anyway. :-)